# How to filter records according to `timestamp` in Spring Data Hadoop?

Tags: spring, hadoop, hbase, spring-data, spring-data-hadoop

I have a hbase table with a sample record as follows:

```
  03af639717ae10eb743253433147e133                 column=u:a, timestamp=1434300763147, value=apple
  10f3d7f8fe8f25d5bdf52343a2601227                 column=u:a, timestamp=1434300763148, value=mapple
  20164b1aff21bc14e94623423a9d645d                 column=u:a, timestamp=1534300763142, value=papple
  44d1cb38271362d20911a723410b2c67                 column=u:a, timestamp=1634300763141, value=scapple
```

I am lost as I was trying to pull out the row values according to the timestamp. I am using `spring data hadoop`.
I was only able to fetch all the records using below code:

```
 private static final byte[] CF_INFO = Bytes.toBytes("u");
 private static final byte[] baseUrl = Bytes.toBytes("a");

 List<Model> allNewsList
            = hbaseTemplate.find(tableName, columnFamily, new RowMapper<News>()
            {
                @Override
                public Model mapRow(Result result, int rowNum)
                throws Exception 
                {
                    String dateString = TextUtils.getTimeStampInLong(result.toString());
                    String rowKey = Bytes.toString(result.getRow());
                    return new Model(                                
                        rowKey,
                        Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, col_a)
                    );
                }
            });
```

How can I apply filter such that I would be able to get records within timestamp `[1434300763147,1534300763142]`.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this would help someone someday.

```
final org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Scan scan = new Scan();
scan.setTimeRange(1434300763147,1534300763142);
final List<Model> yourObjects = hbaseTemplate.find(tableName, scan, mapper);
```

Also, worth a mention, the max value of the timerange is exclusive, so if you want records with that timestamp to be returned, make sure to increment the max value of timerange by 1.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved using Scanner object from Hbase Client.

Comment: If you find the solution, you may want to post your solution and accept it.